# Remove string after slash with condition

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

I'd like to remove the second part in a phrase as long as it is longer than 3 characters (letters and numbers) and add space if the characters are 3 or less.

In the following test set:

```
CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL/HOPITAL CENTRALE DE SOINS
ABC/DEF
FOUNDATION INSTITUTION/FUNDATION DEL INSTITUTO
HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20/20
```

**The result should be**:

```
CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL
ABC DEF
FOUNDATION INSTITUTION
HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20 20
```

My first try was this:

```
([^\/]+$)
```

However, all the strings after the slash are gone because it is lacking of any restriction. I need to include a negative lookforward stating that I need to remove strings when they have more than 3 characters after the slash:

```
text= re.sub(r'(^[^\/]+)(?:[\/])(?![A-Z]{3})',
             r'\1 ',
             text,
             0,
             re.IGNORECASE)
```

I am getting the following which is incorrect:

```
CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL/HOPITAL CENTRALE DE SOINS 
ABC DEF
FOUNDATION INSTITUTION/FUNDATION DEL INSTITUTO 
HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20 20
```

How can I get rid of the slash and string in front of?

Thanks

Comment: You need to begin by stating your question fully, rather than saying what you tried then later fleshing out the question. Your first sentence is fine, but it is an incomplete description of the problem. At that point you need to give your example together with the desired result, something like, "For example, given the following test set ... I wish to return the following: .... Then go ahead and give your code and the erroneous result you obtained. Note that it's confusing to include "(CORRECT)" within your return value.

Comment: As @CarySwoveland pointed out a clear demonstration of input string and expected output string is a must.

Comment: sorry about that, I updated the question to be more understandable.

Comment: Much better! Note that you need to take that approach in every question. The more complete the statement of the problem in words that precedes the example, the better. The goal is to make the statement of the problem so complete and unambiguous that an example is not essential (though generally desirable).

Comment: I see one more requirement from your output. A slash in converted to a space character. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups to capture 1-3 chars A-Z or digits before and after the `/` and use those groups in the replacement with a space in between.

Use an alternation to match  a forward slash followed by the rest of the sting to be removed.

```
\b([A-Z0-9]{1,3})/([A-Z0-9]{1,3})\b|/.*
```

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups

```
r"\1 \2"
```

**Explanation**

- `\b`Word boundary
- `([A-Z0-9]{1,3})` Capture **group 1**, match 1-3 times A-Z or a digit
- `/` Match literally
- `([A-Z0-9]{1,3})` Capture **group 2**, match 1-3 times A-Z or a digit
- `\b` Word boundary
- `|` Or
- `/.*` Match `/` and 0+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5aLEBu/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gmPtIn)

Example code

```
import re

regex = r"\b([A-Z0-9]{1,3})/([A-Z0-9]{1,3})\b|/.*"

text = ("CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL/HOPITAL CENTRALE DE SOINS\n"
    "ABC/DEF\n"
    "FOUNDATION INSTITUTION/FUNDATION DEL INSTITUTO\n"
    "HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20/20")

result = re.sub(regex, r"\1 \2", text)
print (result)
```

Output

```
CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL 
ABC DEF
FOUNDATION INSTITUTION 
HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use regexes? Whats wrong with doing it like this?

```
tests = [
    "CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL/HOPITAL CENTRALE DE SOINS", 
    "ABC/DEF", 
    "FOUNDATION INSTITUTION/FUNDATION DEL INSTITUTO", 
    "HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20/20"
]

for test in tests:
    separate = test.split("/", 1)
    print(separate[0] if len(separate[1])>3 else test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern:

```
text= ["CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL/HOPITAL CENTRALE DE SOINS ",
       "ABC/DEF",
       "FOUNDATION INSTITUTION/FUNDATION DEL INSTITUTO",
       "HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20/20"]

for element in text:
    str_res = re.sub(r'(?:[\/])([A-Z0-9]{0,3}\b)|[^\/]*$',
                     r' \1',
                     element,
                     0,
                     re.IGNORECASE)
    print(str_res)
```